# Placing two MultiCells next to each other using FPDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I trying to create a custom table using FPDF Cell/MultiCell.

My 1st cell is a `MultiCell` that has two lines of text. The next cell should then just be placed right next to it.

**Problem** :  no matter what I do to the next cell, it is always on the next line of the page instead of being placed right next to the 1st cell - and it's driving me crazy.

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'config.php';
require 'fpdf.php';

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,'Certificate of foreign Currency usage in respect of materials and components in terms of the notes to rebate item ',1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(40,10,'DA190',1);
$pdf->Output();
```

The cell containing the text "DA190" should be placed next to the previous cell, but is being positioned underneath the previous cell.

Answer (score 17):

Before printing your first multicell, record the cursor position:

```
$x=$this->GetX();
$y=$this->GetY();
```

add your multicell using `$this->Multicell($w,5,'Content');`

Reset the cursor position to the start height (y) and the start horizontal + the width of the 1st multicell:

```
$this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
```

Add your next multicell and repeat as necessary.

Comment: $w is undefined

Comment: $w is defined. It is the width of the previous cell. If you use MultiCell(123,6,'content'); You can also just use $this->SetXY($x+123,$y); if you dont use a variable for the MultiCell width.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me

```
$pdf->multicell(120, 5, '   ' . $actividad, 0, 'l', true);
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetXY($x + 120, $y);
$pdf->Cell(70, -5, '   ' . $claseActividad, '', 0, 'l', true);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sxVB.png)

Answer (score -5):

I found the solution - fpdf has an extension (#3) focussed on using multicells.

Comment: Can you explain this answer a little bit more? What needs to be added to make the 3 cells fit into one row ? Here is your modified [code](http://pastebin.com/0vmfSTP4).