# FPDF print MultiCell() adjacently

Tags: fpdf

I've googled around and found this question very common but I can't seem to find a proper and direct answer. I'm using FPDF and I want to generate tables using MultiCell() since I need the line break property of it. Tried Cell() but it can't read the line break.

```
$col1="PILOT REMARKS\n\n";
$pdf->MultiCell(189, 10, $col1, 1, 1);
$col2="Pilot's Name and Signature\n".$name;
$pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $col2, 1);
$pdf->Ln(0);
$col3="Date Prepared\n".$date;
$pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $col3, 1);
```

But I can't generate it properly 'cause MultiCell() stacks the result. How can I achieve having MultiCell() printed adjacently with each other in a most simple and easy way?

Found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982375/placing-two-multicells-next-to-each-other-using-fpdf-in-php) but it doesn't provide a clear answer. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try storing the X and Y co-ordinates and then setting them after the write

```
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();

$col1="PILOT REMARKS\n\n";
$pdf->MultiCell(189, 10, $col1, 1, 1);

$pdf->SetXY($x + 189, $y);

$col2="Pilot's Name and Signature\n".$name;
$pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $col2, 1);
$pdf->Ln(0);
$col3="Date Prepared\n".$date;
$pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $col3, 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to [Danny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567996/2305831).  I like keeping the Width of each column stored and then use that when executing the SetXY method.

Example:

```
$x = $this->x;
$y = $this->y;
$push_right = 0;

$this->MultiCell($w = 100,3,"Column\r\nNumber 1",1,'C',1);

$push_right += $w;
$this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);

$this->MultiCell($w = 60,3,"Column\r\nNumber 2",1,'C',1);

$push_right += $w;
$this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);

$this->MultiCell(0,3,"Column 3\r\nFilling in the Rest",1,'C',1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  SetXY(x,y) function to set cursor in pdf .

```
          $pdf->SetXY(x,y);
```

Set cursor to print data in pdf

Where x is x-axis value and y is y-axis value

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. I had to SetXY before each element (for some reason it's reseting to the start of the multicell after write of any element).  So before each and every element, manually SetXY.