# Alignment of multicell in FPDF

Tags: php, cell, fpdf

I am trying to generate pdf using **fpdf** library and php .

I want to pdf output like :

> ```
> ------------               -------------
>  Grad Marks                90%
>  Documnets attched         Mark Sheet, I.C. or TC, Caste
>                            Certificate, Eligibility Form, Bonafide,
>                            Passing Certificate
>  Why do you want to        Because I want to build my career
>  take  admission in        in management field.
>  MBA?
> ```

So I have written a piece of code

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
foreach ($userInputs as $key => $value) {
 $pdf->Ln(7);
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 10);
            $pdf->MultiCell(90.5, 2.7, $key, 0, 'L', false);
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
            $pdf->MultiCell(60, 2.7, $value, 0, 'L', false);
        }
    }
$pdf->Output();
```

N:B - Where $userInput is an **array** contains (Grad Marks,Documnets attched, Why do u ...) as **key** and (90%,Marks sheet..., Because I want ...) as **values**.

But I am not getting the desired output. I am getting out put like

> ```
> ------------              
>  Grad Marks                
>  90%
>  Documnets attched         
>  Mark Sheet, I.C. or TC, Caste
>  Certificate, Eligibility Form, Bonafide,
>  Passing Certificate
>  Why do you want to 
>  take  admission in        
>  MBA?
>  Because I want to build my career
>  in management field.
> ```

So please help me out to get the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been previously answered on StackOverflow. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559330/fpdf-print-multicell-adjacently) for how to get it to work.

Comment: It's working but I found pagebreaks in cells. So please suggest me how to fix the issue.

Comment: I've come across that issue before, but there is no way to prevent it without changing the source of FPDF. I'm not at work to access the code changes I made, but I'm pretty sure I just copied the `MultiCell` function within the source, renamed it to `GetMultiCellHeight` and removed everything in the function except the bits where it calculated the cell height. Then you just need to call `$pdf->GetMultiCellHeight(content)` and check to see if enough space remains on the page. If not add a page break, then finally call `$pdf->MultiCell(content)`.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at example of using `writeHTML()` function at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php

then try something like this

```
$pdf = new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$html ='<table>';
foreach ($userInputs as $key => $value) {
   html.='<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>';  
}
$html .= '</table>';
$pdf->Output();
```