# new line in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using PDO for connection database. this is output from my code:
[image]

I want all cell same line, not change line. i try search in my code to delete if any code with ln(). but not find it. i don't know why it not show beside.

this is my code:

```
$stmt->execute(array('idFotoJaminan'=>$idFotoJaminan));
$result = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//$pdf->Cell(40,10,'LAMPIRAN FOTO\nJAMINAN',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Multicell(40,4,"LAMPIRAN FOTO\nJAMINAN",1,"C");

foreach($result as $row) {
$pdf->Multicell(80,4,'Debitur : '. $row['debitur'],1); 
//$pdf->Ln();
//$pdf->Cell(0,5,'L NAME:', $row['lname']);
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'L NAME:'. $row['debitur'], 0, 0, 'L'); 
//$pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cells are with different width. First `Multicell` is `40` second one inside loop is `80`

```
$pdf->Multicell(40,4,"LAMPIRAN FOTO\nJAMINAN",1,"C");
...
$pdf->Multicell(80,4,'Debitur : '. $row['debitur'],1);
```

Try to make them equal

```
$pdf->Multicell(80,4,"LAMPIRAN FOTO\nJAMINAN",1,"C");
...
$pdf->Multicell(80,4,'Debitur : '. $row['debitur'],1);
```

Then if you don't want `LAMPIRAN FOTO\nJAMINAN` to go on new line remove `\n` from it.

Here is good example with [table and `Multicells`](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php):

Comment: i have try to make all Multicell equal like your example. still not work

Comment: Did you also check the example page which I linked in my answer?

Comment: yes, but i cannot understand it. i am not interesting using array

Comment: thanks for your solution. i found solution on :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559330/fpdf-print-multicell-adjacently

Comment: Glad you found solution.

Comment: Thanks, solution is: Setting X and Y.$pdf->SetXY($x, $y);