# FPDF Multicell text wrapping

Tags: php, fpdf

hello kind sir's may you help me with my problem. Please i need for my thesis. what i is want to wrap the text in my cell using multi cell. I try to watch videos and look for the same question here but i cant fix. Please help me understand how to do it. It would be very helpul if you give me examples or is there a better pdf generator.

this is my code

```
<?php
require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srdatabase");  

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        $this->Cell(100, 10, 'Reports', 0,1);
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
        $this->SetFillColor(180, 180, 255);
        $this->SetDrawColor(50,50,100);
        $this->Cell(26,10,'Full Name',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(25,10,'Specialization',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(190,10,'Description',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(22,10,'Reserved Count',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(18,10,'Date Added',1,1,'',true);
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm', 'A4');
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);
$pdf->setFont('Arial','',7);
$pdf->setDrawColor(50,50,100);

if(empty($_POST["from_date"]) && empty($_POST["to_date"])&& isset($_POST["search_text"])) 
{
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["search_text"]);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT * FROM speakers 
    WHERE speaker_fullname LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR speaker_image LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR speaker_specialization LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR speaker_description LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR speaker_paymentcost LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR speaker_reservedcount LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR date_added LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    ORDER BY date_added DESC"); 

    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $pdf->Cell(26,10,$data['speaker_fullname'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,10,$data['speaker_specialization'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(190,10,$data['speaker_description'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(22,10,$data['speaker_reservedcount'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(18,10,$data['date_added'],1,1);
    }
}
```

this is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: You aren't using MultiCell so I don't know what you are expecting. http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably want the `$data['speaker_description']` to wrap when it is too long. At any rate, if that isn't the one, you can do this to all of columns.

You can use FPDFs `GetStringWidth()` to see if it would be greater than the width you have proposed and them make use `MultiCell()` on each column rather than `Cell()`. Also, please note that if you are not specifying `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak( false);`, you will need to do that ( adding pages when you reach the bottom ) and make sure the last cell of the wouldn't overflow into the page below before adding a new page.

Comment: i tried to make it multicell but it mess up the row below it. So if you give me an example it would be really helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559330/fpdf-print-multicell-adjacently you will basically replace all of your cell calls with MultiCell