# Fpdf creating new line after new data

Tags: php, pdf

I changed Cell() to Multicell() in a table to include break lines inside a cell.

I don't know why it is breking the line after each new data. I mean, the header and corresponding data should be all in one line:

> Name | Last Name | Exemple of breaking line

but what's happening is:

> Name
>
> Last Name
>
> Exemple of breaking line

php:

```
<?php

$pdf->Multicell(200, 20, 'Motorista',1);
$pdf->Multicell(60, 20, 'Direção',1);
$pdf->Multicell(60, 15, "Espera Pós \nJornada",1,'C');
$pdf->Multicell(60, 15, "Espera em \nJornada",1,'C');
$pdf->Multicell(60, 20, 'Noturnas',1);
$pdf->Multicell(70, 20, 'Extras 50%',1);
$pdf->Multicell(70, 20, 'Extras 100%',1);
$pdf->Multicell(60, 15, "Hrs Tempo \nParado",1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
$pdf->Ln(10);

?>
```

I removed `$pdf->Ln(10);` but this is just for adding margin from header to data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13559330/10285255)

```
<?php

$x = $pdf->GetX(); 
$y = $pdf->GetY();

$pdf->Multicell(200, 30, 'Motorista',1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 200, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 30, 'Direção',1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 260, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 15, "Espera Pós \nJornada",1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 320, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 15, "Espera em \nJornada",1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 380, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 30, 'Noturnas',1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 440, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 30, 'Extras 50%',1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 500, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 30, 'Extras 100%',1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 560, $y);

$pdf->Multicell(60, 15, "Hrs Tempo \nParado",1,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 620, $y);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
$pdf->Ln(30);

?>
```

So you sum the previous col width to the next one.